# What regex pattern would I have to use to parse out unwanted characters in this format?

Tags: regex, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
POSIX qw(strftime);
my $time =  strftime("%YT%mT%d TTTT%H:%M", localtime);
print ("Todays date and time is $time\n");
```

I am a little rusty at regex, what would be a pattern to search and replace the following output. 2014T03T21 TTTT15:37? I just would like the date to be displayed. If you know of a method other than regex that would be great also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the pattern you've given, and the capture groups in parentheses to pick out the three components you want:
`(\d{4})T(\d{2})T(\d{2}) TTTT\d{2}:\d{2}`

This will capture the year, month and date. When matching, you can assign these to three variables using the following syntax:

```
$time =~ m/(\d{4})T(\d{2})T(\d{2}) TTTT\d{2}:\d{2}/;
my ($year, $month, $day) = ($1, $2, $3);
```

There are many online tools that will expand and explain regex patterns.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it in regexcoach. I think what I was trying to ask was about the capturing.